# Rails select tag in form doesn't populate with value in the edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

I have the typical rails _form generated by scaffold for a member model. For the param :state I am using a select tag:

```
 <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states),  { :include_blank=>true, :prompt =>  'State' }, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

Using a helper method (us states):

```
def us_states
[
['AK', 'AK'],
['AL', 'AL'], #etc
```

And for the param "member_since" I am using the select_year helper:

```
<%= select_year(0, {:start_year => 2013, :end_year => 1920, :field_name => 'member_since', :prompt => 'Choose year', prefix: :member}, {:class => "form-control"} )   %>
```

Now both of these selects work to create a new record, but neither field is pre-filled in the edit record view. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :state, us_states,  { :include_blank=>true, :prompt =>  'State' }, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

and

```
<%= select_year(f.object.member_since, {:start_year => 2013, :end_year => 1920, :field_name => 'member_since', :prompt => 'Choose year', prefix: :member}, {:class => "form-control"} )   %>
```

UPDATE:

Since member_since is a string, you will need to convert it to date:

```
 <%= select_year(Date.new(f.object.member_since.to_i), {:start_year => 2013, :end_year => 1920, :field_name => 'member_since', :prompt => 'Choose year', prefix: :member}, {:class => "form-control"} )   %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! The state select field now works. However, the member_since select is throwing an action controller error: undefined method `year' for "2008":String

Comment: That's what you get for storing years as a string :) You can change the data column to Date, or use un padted code (I'll update it in sec)

Comment: Great point :| Changed field type and now works perfectly. Thanks again