# f.select not preselecting value while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-helpers

I have a field `state_id` for which I am using select dropdown:

```haml
= form.select :state_id, options_for_select(states), {}, prompt: 'Select State'
```

But while editing the form it doesn't preselect the current value of `state_id`. I know I can pass `:selected` param to pass the default selected value:

```haml
options_for_select(states, @object.state_id)
```

But as this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models) suggest I don't need to use those options.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** It's a nested attribute and other fields are working fine with `f.text_field` but not `f.select`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but does the `prompt:` override the selection?

Comment: `states` - what does this return ?

Comment: states = `[[ "Alabama", 1 ], [ "Alaska", 2 ], [ "Arizona", 3 ]]`

Comment: @ollpu No, I tried with just `= form.select :state_id, options_for_select(states)` as well

Comment: There appears to be a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497503/rails-select-tag-in-form-doesnt-populate-with-value-in-the-edit-view, in which you just refer to states as the second argument, without options_for_select. If that's not working, can you share your related controller and form?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
= select_tag "state_id", options_from_collection_for_select(states, "id", "name",@object.state_id), prompt: "Select State", placeholder: "Select State"
```

Hope it'll do the job for you.